# How do i diff two files from the web

Tags: unix, curl, pipe, diff, command-line-interface

I want to see the differences of 2 files that not in the local filesystem but on the web. So, i think if have to use `diff`, `curl` and some kind of piping.

Something like

```
curl http://to.my/file/one.js http://to.my/file.two.js | diff
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Write them to the local filesystem? :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The UNIX tool `diff` can compare two files. If you use the `<()` expression, you can compare the output of the command within the indirections:

```
diff <(curl file1) <(curl file2)
```

So in your case, you can say:

```
diff <(curl -s http://to.my/file/one.js) <(curl -s http://to.my/file.two.js)
```

Comment: Nice one, I would add **-s** to make curl silent and compare only contents, like: 
`diff <(curl -s http://to.my/file/one.js) <(curl -s http://to.my/file.two.js)`

Answer (score 1):

Some people arriving at this page might be looking for a line-by-line diff rather than a code-diff. If so, and with coreutils, you could use:

```
comm -23 <(curl http://to.my/file/one.js | sort) \
         <(curl http://to.my/file.two.js | sort)
```

To get lines in the first file that are not in the second file. You could use `comm -13` to get lines in the second file that are not in the first file.

If you're not restricted to coreutils, you could also use [sd](https://github.com/MarianoGappa/sd) (stream diff), which doesn't require sorting nor process substitution and supports infinite streams, like so:

```
curl http://to.my/file/one.js | sd 'curl http://to.my/file.two.js'
```

The fact that it supports infinite streams allows for some interesting use cases: you could use it with a curl inside a `while(true)` loop (assuming the page gives you only "new" results), and `sd` will timeout the stream after some specified time with no new streamed lines.

Here's a [blogpost](http://marianogappa.github.io/software/2016/07/30/diffing-streams-on-the-terminal/) I wrote about diffing streams on the terminal, which introduces `sd`.